# Why a continuous function cannot map rational numbers to irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

There is a question in Goldbergs analysis book as below:

> Prove there is no continuous real-valued function f on real numbers such that f(x) is rational if x is irrational and f(x) is irrational if x is rational.

But why should the statement above be correct?
Let $f(x)=\pi x$ , continuous -real valued;
and let $x=1$, a rational number;
then $f(1)=\pi$ is irrational.

Clearly I must show the statement in that question is correct. But I do not know why?

Comment: And if $x=\sqrt 2$?

Comment: The function $f$ in question needs to satisfy that for **every** rational $x$ we have $f(x)$ irrational and vice versa. Not just for one $x$.

Comment: Hint:  Show that no constant works (easy).  Then, if $f(a)>f(b)$ argue that there aren't enough rationals to cover all the irrationals between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.